# Regular Expressions: parsing through multiple captures

Tags: c#, regex, expresso

Good morning.  I have the following line returned from a device

```
♥☺i20100☺i2010018032809120110000074653B0F4465275D245EAA80042D82F5E000000004291D83C00000000022000007460042FD45FE7F2A4648C0004282FC0400000000429799E500000000033000007466A869946694E8145BCF80042EF811B00000000428CCAF400000000044000007461DFFC4461D1D61462B040042A15A6600000000428E635100000000&&C631♥
```

The data comes back in blocks of 6 characters after the date-time stamp. I'm trying to get past the date-time and look for all blocks of 6 that begin with 42.  There should be 3 blocks returned.
Using Expresso, I can get **all** the blocks of `.*i20100.i20100(?<Date>.{10})(?<AANNTT>.{6})+`

but how can I make a subquery on each of those and return all the ones starting with 42?  I thought it might be this: `.*i20100.i20100(?<Date>.{10})(.{6})*(?<AANNTT>42.{4})+`

but that's only returning the last one.

Thanks in advance!
-Dave

Comment: Not sure if I butchered your question with code blocks, but it's not clear what is and isn't part of the string/code/etc. Please clean it up properly if I screwed something up. It was illegible in its previous state.

Comment: I just made one quick edit, but thanks for cleaning that up.

Comment: So, just to be clear, the 1st code bock can return ALL of my groups <AANNTT> but I want to filter that and only return the 6-block groups beginning with 42 (there should be 3 of them).

Comment: I was also able to go to http://regexstorm.net/tester and enter my expression and the text to test it against and see the 1st expression returns 1 match for DATE and 44 matches for group AANNTT but the 2nd expression only captures DATE and 1 match for AANTT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
(?<=i20100.i20100(?<Date>.{10})(?:.{6})*?)42.{4}
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c%3di20100.i20100%28%3f%3cDate%3e.%7b10%7d%29%28%3f%3a.%7b6%7d%29*%3f%2942.%7b4%7d&i=%e2%99%a5%e2%98%bai20100%e2%98%bai2010018032809120110000074653B0F4465275D245EAA80042D82F5E000000004291D83C00000000022000007460042FD45FE7F2A4648C0004282FC0400000000429799E500000000033000007466A869946694E8145BCF80042EF811B00000000428CCAF400000000044000007461DFFC4461D1D61462B040042A15A6600000000428E635100000000%26%26C631%e2%99%a5)

**Details**

- `(?<=i20100.i20100(?<Date>.{10})(?:.{6})*?)` - a positive lookahead that matches a location in a string that is immediately preceded with

  - `i20100.i20100` - `i20100`, and char but a newline, `i20100`
  - `(?<Date>.{10})(?:.{6})*?` - Group `Date` that matches 10 chars other than a newline, then any 0+ repetitions of any 6 chars but a newline, as few as possible
- `42.{4}` - `42` and then any 4 chars other than a newline

[image]

Comment: That is PERFECT, thanks.  I didn't know about the LookAhead feature